# Different 404 pages being returned from ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have got a plain ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet application. When I go to /NotFound, I get his error page:

[image]

while if I go to /Home/About/something/nonexistent, I get

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's happening under the hood?

I've gone in GetControllerInstance of the DefaultControllerFactory class in System.Web.Mvc and I can see:

```
throw new HttpException(404,
String.Format(
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
    MvcResources.DefaultControllerFactory_NoControllerFound,
    requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
```

but I can't figure out where that exception is being handled. Am I on the right track there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **first case** is a *.NET* error page - because your /NotFound URL is covered by your routes, but the controller isn't found. In other words, MVC handles the request because it has routes that match it (e.g. `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` where all three parameters are optional or have defaults), but then finds that it's in over its head.

Assuming you're using the default routes, the exception is indeed thrown by `GetControllerInstance` - because there's no `NotFoundController`.

Going instead to "/Home/NotFound" would throw a similar exception (also a 404 `HttpException`) from `Controller.HandleUnknownAction`, because "NotFound" now is used as the action name.

In your **second case**, the URL doesn't match any route, so MVC doesn't handle it - instead *IIS* tries to handle it itself, and shows its *own* 404 page, because it also doesn't find any other handlers or actual files at the path indicated by the URL.

As for how to handle all those cases, [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc) should help.

The short version of where the exception thrown from `GetControllerInstance` is handled is "it isn't - in any place that you have control of". You can either use the global `Application_Error` method in global.asax, or use one of the many other approaches in the linked question (for example, replacing the controller factory with one that has `GetControllerInstance` overridden to add exception handling closer to where the problem occurs).